# Copying RAII object in C++

Tags: c++, raii

I am reading Effective C++, in `Rule 14: Think carefully about copying behavior in resource-managing classes`, there is an example:

```
class Lock {
  public:
    explicit Lock(Mutex* pm) : mutexPtr(pm) {
      lock(mutexPtr);
    }
    ~Lock() {
      unlock(mutexPtr);
    }
  private:
    Mutex *mutexPtr;
};
```

It points out that if we construct the `Lock` as above, there will be a problem if we run the code below:

```
Mutex m;
Lock ml1(&m);
Lock ml2(ml1);
```

I think it may because the code may runs like below:

```
// ml1 constructes
lock(m)
// copy ml2, but ml1.mutexPtr and ml2.mutexPtr both point to m
ml2.mutexPtr = ml1.mutexPtr
// ml1 destructs
unlock(m)
// ml2 destructs
unlock(m)
```

So the m will be unlock for twice. So is it the real reason that cause the problem below? thx!

Comment: Which version of the book is this? "Item 14" in my version is about virtual destructors...

Comment: Effective C++: 55 Specific  Ways to Improve Your Programs and Designs [Version 3]

Comment: Oh, I have version 2... sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is why the author is saying to be careful. If you use a recursive_mutex instead of plain mutex you can simply lock in the copy ctor and copy-assign operator, but if it's a non-recursive mutex it would likely be better to make the lock type non-copyable.